# Junit test cases fails when executed together

Tags: junit4

I have created a test case which consists of multiple tests (`@Test` methods), each needs an environment variable, which I have set in Run Configuration. Now, whenever I am executing the complete test case, then it fails. However, if I run each of the test methods separately, then it is executing successfully.

Its quite strange, but if anybody can help me solve this?

Comment: Yes but will you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Provide the relevant of your test class.

Comment: Also if all methods executed together fail, is a clear cut indication IMO that the tests are dependent on each other or are altering some state and are dependent on some shared state.

Comment: Lucky shot - concurrency issue in tested features. Better provide code of failing tests + luncher configuration.

Comment: @Nikhil Did you find any solution? Even I am facing the same type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your unit test is a unit test**

That means it should not be dependent on the success or failure of any other test cases and run successful independently. Here it is quite clear that when you are running all of your test cases together some of your test cases are changing certain information or data which your this particular test is expecting.

Comment: All my test cases are independent, but if any of the test case fails we exit the JVM, but this is happening only in case when we run all the test cases in one go. However, when we execute each of them separately, it is executed successfully. Also, I have to run each of the test cases in new session, how can I do that using jUnit. Please suggest.